# need to combine 3 sql-statement into 1

Tags: sql, postgresql, union

I have 3 SQL-Statements that I would like to combine into just one so I dont have to make multiple requests to my database from my programm (java).
My DB is PostgreSQL 9.4

First one creates a new user in umgmt_users

```
INSERT INTO umgmt_users ("user") VALUES ('test1')
```

Second one gets the id of that user (db is postgres and id data type is serial, so it get assigned automatically with me/the programm not knowing what id the user will get

```
SELECT umgmt_users.id
FROM umgmt_users
WHERE umgmt_users.user = 'test1'
```

Thrird is to add the just created user with his id (which I need the second statement for) and some other values into a different table

```
INSERT INTO
umgmt_user_oe_fac_role ("user_id", "oe_id", "fac_id", "role_id")
VALUES ('ID OF USER test1 created in first statement', '1', '2', '1');
```

Is there a way to get all three Statements into one?

1. create user
2. look up the ID he got assigned
3. insert his ID + other values into a different table

I'm not that good at SQL, I tried to put brackets around the select and put it into the insert & also looked at UNION and WITH but can not get it to work...

**EDIT: Ended up using this solution from [a_horse_with_no_name](https://stackoverflow.com/users/330315/a-horse-with-no-name)**

```
with new_user as (
   INSERT INTO umgmt_users ("user") VALUES ('test1')
   returning id
) 
INSERT INTO umgmt_user_oe_fac_role (user_id, oe_id, fac_id, role_id)
SELECT id, 1, 2, 1
FROM new_user;
```

Comment: Just create a postgres function, put all 3 statements there and call the function from java.

Comment: what you want is a `transaction`, this will require a `stored procedure` at least.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson: a transaction does not _require_ a stored procedure (or function as Postgres does not have procedures)

Answer (score 1):

All you need is two inserts:

```
INSERT INTO umgmt_users ("user") VALUES ('test1');
INSERT INTO umgmt_user_oe_fac_role (user_id, oe_id, fac_id, role_id)
VALUES (lastval(), 1, 2, 1);
```

In order for `lastval()` to work correctly there must be no other statement between the two inserts and the **have** to be run in a single transaction (so autocommit needs to be turned off)

---

Alternatively you can use a data modifying CTE which is then executed as a **single** statement:

```
with new_user as (
   INSERT INTO umgmt_users ("user") VALUES ('test1')
   returning id
) 
INSERT INTO umgmt_user_oe_fac_role (user_id, oe_id, fac_id, role_id)
SELECT id, 1, 2, 1
FROM new_user;
```

---

Please don't put numbers in single quotes.

Comment: ended up using your CTE solution which worked fine, the first one did not work for me but thats ok ;) thx a lot :):):)

Comment: @Alkahna: the first one should work. What was the problem? Also: do not change your question to include the answer you have chosen. If you want your question marked as "answered" you need to accept the answer that solved your problem

Answer (score -2):

The answer to this is : It's impossible to combine these into a single plain vanilla ANSI SQL statement.

The first and third ones talk about two different tables altogether. 
The second one is a Select Statement which is a different type of statement from the other two.

Comment: It **is** possible in a single statement, see my answer.